# Use Oracle Partition and Over By clause to retrieve section numbers

Tags: oracle11g

My Table comprises 4 Columns (Patient, Sample, Analysis and Component). I am trying to write a query that will look at the combination of Patient, Analysis and Component for each record and assign a "Section Number". 
The numbering should re-start for every patient.

See expected output below. Patient 1010 has 3 samples but all have same Analysis-component. Hence they all have the same section (1). 
Now, counting restarts for Patient 2020. This patient has 2 samples but both have a different Analysis-Component combination. Hence they are placed in separate sections 1 and 2.

```
Patient   Sample       Analysis     Component       Section Number       
_______   ______       ________     _________       ______________
1010    720000140249    CALC        Calcium               1
1010    720000140288    CALC        Calcium               1
1010    720000140288    CALC        Calcium               1
2020    720000190504    ALB         Albumin               1
2020    720000160504    ALB         Albumin Pct           2
3030    720000134568    CALC        Calcium               1
3030    720000123404    ALB         Albumin               2
3030    720000160765    ALB         Albumin Pct           3
```

I have written the following query but all it does is groups samples with the same Component into one section. It does not consider the Patient or Analysis at all.

Your help is much appreciated (as always!)

```
select
x.patient, x.sample_number, x.analysis, x.component
a.myRowCount
from
 X_PREV_PAT_RESULTS x inner join (
   select distinct
    x1.COMPONENT
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY x1.COMPONENT) myRowCount
   from X_PREV_PAT_RESULTS x1
   group by  x1.patient  ) A on x.COMPONENT = A.COMPONENT
order by a.myRowCount, x.patient;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select x.patient, x.sample_number, x.analysis, x.component,
       dense_rank() over(partition by x.patient order by x.analysis, x.component)
from X_PREV_PAT_RESULTS x 
where exists (select 1 from X_PREV_PAT_RESULTS x1 where x1.COMPONENT = x.COMPONENT);
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you want

```
dense_rank() over (partition by patient
                       order by analysis desc, component) myRowCount
```

What happens with rows after a tie? If patient 1010 gets an ALB analysis?  Would that have a `MyRowCount` of 2?  Or 4?  `rank` would return 4.  `dense_rank` would return 2.

How are you determining the order of rows for a partiticular patient?  It appears that you're going in reverse alphabetical order for `analysis` and then alphabetically for `component` but that seems like a pretty unusual ordering.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If the rows tie, it is OK to skip a number. Also, I do not have any specific ordering requirements. Sorry, 
I'm not sure what part of my query indicates reverse alphabetical ordering for analysis. If you could point that out, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @ERS - For patient 3030, you have the CALC row coming before the ALB rows.  And you have the Albumin Pct row coming after the Albumin row.  That's where I inferred the ordering that you wanted.

Comment: I see - Sorry about the confusion. However I am not able to get the desired output with either rank or dense_rank. This works very well for Patient Records where there is only one Analysis=Component combination for several samples. In cases where there are different combinations, it is not giving me the desire output. I am seeing some records where the same section number (or rank) is applied to records that have a different analysis-component combination. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @ERS dense_rank() should work well. Maybe you are using it in a wrong place. I'm going to give another answer to show the sql, but this answer is correct.

Comment: @ERS - Do you have a sample of the data that is creating the issue (and the desired and actual output)?  If two rows have different `analysis` and `component` values for the same `patient`, both `rank` and `dense_rank` would produce different values.

Comment: @JustinCave - Yes, you are right - the values were different. Also, I had not used the dense_rank correctly. Thank you for your help.